# C++ else statement only if Macro is define

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, c++14

I'm trying to do an if/else statement. But I want to wrap the else statement in an `#ifdef` macro test.

```
if (check1)
{
...
}
#ifdef MACRO
else 
{...}
#endif
```

is this allowed?

Comment: Yea it is allowed but why is it necessary to do it this way?

Comment: I'm adding experimental codes and I need the old code to continue

Comment: bet you can do it with templates - you've tagged C++14. Macros are from the 1970s.

Comment: The code is already using templates and that will require a lot of changes to be made. With the Macros, I can have separate the experimental code. At least that is my understanding/hope.

Comment: I think best way to verify is to compile your code. If compiles then debug and see if code within `MACRO` is being skipped or not. You'll get your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor runs before the compiler. If the preprocessor evaluates the macro and generates valid c/c++ code (like the example you've included), it's a valid usage.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can, its `C`. Preprocessor evaluate this before compiler so compiler just see this

```
if (check1)
{
...
}
```

---

But you cant/shouldn't do this

```
#ifdef MACRO
if (check1)
{
...
}
#endif
else 
{...}
```

Answer (score 2):

> is this allowed?

Yes, this is valid. What are your doubts in particular?